# css3 scrolling instead without a page reload

Tags: css, scroll, reload

I follow this example

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

But it does not work, page is reloaded. I need only to scroll, instead of reload.

Actually i would like to scroll all body to the certain id item.

// html5

```
<nav>
  <a href="#page-1" rel='no-refresh' >1</a>
  <a href="#page-2" rel='no-refresh' >2</a>
  <a href="#page-3" rel='no-refresh' >3</a>
</nav>
<scroll-container>
  <scroll-page id="page-1" >1</scroll-page>
  <scroll-page id="page-2">2</scroll-page>
  <scroll-page id="page-3">3</scroll-page>
</scroll-container>
```

// css3

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav, scroll-container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
nav {
  width: 339px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
scroll-container {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
scroll-page {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

Comment: I tried on jsfiddle and it works. Maybe you use wrong browser that doesn't support this feature?

Answer (score 2):

This feature is only fully supported by Firefox 36 currently.  Neither Internet Explorer or Safari support this feature at all.

To make it work with Chrome or Opera, you will need to go into your browser settings and enable the "Smooth Scrolling" or "Enable experimental web platform features" flag.

Side Note: The page you linked to contains information about browser compatibility for future reference.  This code should not be used for production environments due to the lack of implementation across browsers.

If you want to add smooth scrolling to a production environment I would recommend a javascript based implementation for now.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it was Chrome. I really would like css to have all features. LIke possibility in insert values in inputs, make checkboxes checked, and submit buttons with forms.